# How to send Outlook mail when port 25 blocked in intranet

Tags: windows-7, email, exchange, smtp

We have a build server which runs daily builds. We want to send email to project leaders after each build with details (success, fail, etc). The problem we have is that we don't have access to port 25. We are using MS Exchange as mail server.

Is there a solution to send automatic emails?

Will a local mail server solve this issue? (We are using Windows 7 on the build machine)

We are mainly searching for a solution as IT department is not willing to allow us access to port 25.

Thank you,
Iulian

Comment: Just change the port that Outlook will use, port 25 is standard, its not a requirement.  Of course you will have to change the exchange server port also for this to work.

Comment: Ask them to open a new connector for your build server

Comment: I don't have access to Exchange server's configuration. I cannot the port on which SMTP service will be listening.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg What is a connector? Can you please provide a reference link, so that I can know what to ask?

Comment: These might help: http://serverfault.com/a/573495/61246 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996395(v=exchg.150).aspx